# Source material desired for behavior of derivatives of action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I'm basically looking for concise commentary, and especially source material/ short discussion pertaining to the following, which I will (emphasizing loosely) state as follows:

Suppose a given action $S$ is extremized, i.e satisfies the pertinent Euler Lagrange equation. The topic I'm looking for is something quantifying the behavior of it's derivative(s).... which I know is vague, but phrased vaguely because I'm not trying to pinpoint the discussion too narrowly.

For simple example by analogy:  Let's entertain the case where $S$ quantifies the arclength in Euclidean space.   It's extremized as a 'straight' line, i.e. the shortest distance between two points (in that setup).   Now, consider it's (full) derivative with respect to distance along the arc.   It would 'seem' that this thing is also extremized.  The arclength is a minimum.  BUT, clearly in this case, the amount that $S$ changes with respect to a change in the parameter the Lagrangian is integrated over, is also a minimum at each point along the distance.

However I'm looking for more broad discussion, proof, disproof, of treatment of cases in general.  If $S\rightarrow $ minimum/extremum is $d S\over d\lambda$ also implied to be min/ extremum?  Discussion for the converse of that statement would be interesting as well.

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v2): Work out a couple of easy examples, and see what happens in these cases. Then modify and clarify the question accordingly.